# How to ignore Page Editor values at Html.Sitecore().Rendering

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I need to render some control only in normal mode,

I mean when Page Editor show page control should contain only real values not HTML code what allows to edit data.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering(Model.MetaRenderingId)
```

what parameters I need to use for it ?

Comment: So you want to make particular component not editable?

Comment: @MarekMusielak lets say yes !

Comment: Seeing as your rendering in this case most likely is a meta tag rendering and you never want to have it editable, can't you unclick the "Editable" field on the presentation item in Sitecore?

Comment: Isn't this something you need to control in the rendering itself instead of on the request to render it?

Comment: If you don't need your fields to be editable don't use Sitecore API or controls, as example if you are using web forms; don't use <sc:Text .../>.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply disable the webedit functionality by using the DisableWebEdit property of an anonymous object.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering(Model.MetaRenderingId, new { DisableWebEdit = true })}
```